# update not working when using ON DUPLICATE KEY clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, on-duplicate-key

I found several similar question on SO, but I'm new to PDO and couldn't successfully adapt the code for my criteria..
i don't know why this code not working .
i don't know why this code not working .
i don't know why this code not working .
i have table users .
i have form post 
my code html form select and code php .

```
 <form method="POST" name="setform">
                <div class="moncompte">
                        <!-- pseudo-->  <label class="moncompteLabel" >Pseudo</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="pseudo" class="moncompteInput" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="moncompte">
                        <!-- nom--> <label class="moncompteLabel">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="fullname" class="moncompteInput" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="moncompte">
                        <!-- email-->   <label class="moncompteLabel">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="moncompteInput" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="moncompte"> 
                         <!-- sexe-->   <label class="moncompteLabel"> Sélectionnez sexe </label>
                                <select name="genre" title="sexe" class="moncompteSelect">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Homme</option>
                                        <option value="1">Femme</option>
                                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="moncompte">
                   <!-- date--> <label class="moncompteLabel"> Date de naissance</label>
                            <div class="dateSelect">
                                    <select name="naissanceJ" title="jour" class="naissanceSelect" >
                                        <option value="0">jour</option>
                                        <option value="1" selected="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                      </select>
                                      <select name="naissanceM" title="mois"  class="naissanceSelect">
                                        <option value="0">mois</option>
                                        <option value="1" selected="1">jan</option>
                                        <option value="2">fév</option>
                                        <option value="3">ma</option>
                                        <option value="4">avr</option>
                                      </select>
                                    <select name="naissanceA" title="année" class="naissanceSelect">
                                        <option value="0">année</option>
                                        <option value="2018" selected="1">2018</option>
                                        <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                        <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                      </select>
                            </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="moncompte">
            <input type="submit" name="enregistrer" value="enregistrer" class="moncompteSub">
                </div>

    </form>
```

code php

```
  $idd = trim(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']));
$id = filter_var($idd, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);


    $pseudo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
    $fullname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $genre = htmlspecialchars($_POST['genre']);

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users(pseudo,email,naissancej,naissancem,naissancea,genre,fullname)
VALUES(:pseudo,:email,:naissancej,:naissancem,:naissancea,
:genre,:fullname) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
     pseudo=:pseudo2,
     email=:email2,
     naissancej=:naissanceJ2,
     naissancem=:naissanceM2,
     naissancea=:naissanceA2,
     genre=:genre2,
     fullname=:fullname2 WHERE id=5 ");

$stmt->execute(array(
        ':pseudo'=> $pseudo,
        ':email'=> $email,
        ':naissancej'=> $naissanceJ,
         ':naissancem'=> $naissanceM,
        ':naissancea'=> $naissanceA,
        ':genre'=> $genre,
        ':fullname'=> $fullname,

        ':pseudo2'=> $pseudo,
        ':email2'=> $email,
        ':naissancej2'=> $naissanceJ,
         ':naissancem2'=> $naissanceM,
        ':naissancea2'=> $naissanceA,
        ':genre2'=> $genre,
        ':fullname2'=> $fullname
    ));
```

Comment: you need to tell the meaning of *why this code not working* ?

Comment: error PDO , syntaxe not correct

Answer (score 0):

`INSERTS` don't have a `WHERE` clause! Remove this.

```
INSERT INTO users 
(pseudo,email,naissancej,naissancem,naissancea,genre,fullname)
VALUES
(:pseudo,:email,:naissancej,:naissancem,:naissancea,:genre,:fullname)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  pseudo=:pseudo2,
  email=:email2,
  naissancej=:naissanceJ2,
  naissancem=:naissanceM2,
  naissancea=:naissanceA2,
  genre=:genre2,
  fullname=:fullname2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the **[documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**, you have `WHERE` clause at the end and that causing the error, please note, you have already mentioned 
`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and it will take care of updating specific row.

```
fullname=:fullname2 WHERE id=5
```

should be just

```
fullname=:fullname2
```

Comment: To be more concrete, it's not that you _don't need to_, it's _an error when you do_. ;)